# Index Match Concatenate for multiple criteria not working in excel

Tags: excel

My index - match - CONCATENATE is not working if range array has one row only.

[image: Not working]

[image]

[image]

This is my function:

```
=INDEX(RETURN_TO_SUPP_TRX[COST],MATCH(CONCATENATE(RETURN_TO_SUPPLIER_HEADER[PO NUM],[@[ITEM CODE]]),CONCATENATE(RETURN_TO_SUPP_TRX[PO NUM],RETURN_TO_SUPP_TRX[ITEM CODE]),0))
```

I did cntrl+shift+enter but still same issue.

The issue happens if the lookup range for MATCH is 1 row.
If it is more than 1 row it works fine.

I traced the issue and found that the match is not able to match although it is finding the lookup array as seen in the screen shot.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you add some sample data together with expected results in order that we can see what your structured table looks like?

Comment: @Jeeped: I added screen shots of the tables with table names.
Let me know if it is still note clear.

Comment: @Jeeped btw; expected result should be 1 as this is the matching row in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't actually spend a lot of time with structured tables and this buggy behavior is a main reason why. If you change the formula to include the headers in the RETURN_TO_SUPP_TRX table *and* add a Total Row, you can get past a single row not being recognized when two columns are concatenated.

Your array formula becomes,

```
=INDEX(RETURN_TO_SUPP_TRX[[#All],[cost]],MATCH(RETURN_TO_SUPPLIER_HEADER[po num]&[@[item code]],RETURN_TO_SUPP_TRX[[#All],[po num]]&RETURN_TO_SUPP_TRX[[#All],[item code]], 0))
```

You also need to go into Table Tools ► Design ► Table Style Options and add a **Total row** to the RETURN_TO_SUPP_TRX table.

Comment: FWIW, I will pass this behavior along to some MS Excel contacts I have made.

Comment: It worked! Had to include the header of trx table as you said. Seems to be a bug as you said. Thanks a lot